# How to search on queried documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie in Elasticsearch and I am facing a problem. My task is searching on a set of documents. For example, I have data with struct like this:

```
type Doc struct{
   id string
   project_id string
   code string
   name string
   status string
}
```

But the difficult thing is I what to get all the documents with project_id=abc then search on them by any other fields (code,name,status) that match the keyword 'test' (for example). How can I do that in Elasticsearch query, please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: can you please share your index mapping, sample index data and your expected search result ?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
GET /[index_name]/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "some text here"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "project_id.keyword": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can use a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) that matches documents matching
> boolean combinations of other queries.

**`must` is the same as logical AND operator and `should` is the same as logical OR operator**

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "project_id":"abc",
  "code": "a",
  "name":"bhavya",
  "status":"engineer"
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "project_id":"abc",
  "code": "a",
  "name":"bhavya",
  "status":"student"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "project_id":"def",
  "code": "a",
  "name":"deeksha",
  "status":"engineer"
}
```

**Search Query:**

The given query satisfies the condition that `"project_id" = "abc"` AND `"name" : "bhavya"` AND `"status":"student"`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "project_id": "abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "bhavya"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "student"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64274465",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.7021472,
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "project_id": "abc",
          "code": "a",
          "name": "bhavya",
          "status": "student"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @iamatsundere181 I don't think you will get any 404 error message, as the `match` queries are enclosed in the `must` clause. I have tried the above query locally, and it works perfectly fine. Can you please try again, and let me know if your issue is resolved?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Great @iamatsundere181 !! If my answer, helped you resolve your issue then please don't forget to upvote my answer as well 

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe using Logstash and filtering some data can help you.